# Bytebuddy: how to defineField within a loop

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I would like to add fields at runtime from a map `Map <String, Class<?>> properties` , such that I can loop through the entries of the `properties` to define fields of the dynamic class

```
new ByteBuddy()
  .defineField(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Rafael Winterhalter  actually, it should be:

```
DynamicType.Builder<?> builder = ...

for (Map.Entry<String, Class<?>> entry : properties.entrySet()) {
    builder = builder.defineField(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue();
}
```

But your answer gave me guidance to get the correct one, so thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Just loop over the immutable builder and mutate it in every step:

```
DynamicType.Builder<?> builder = ...
for (Map.Entry<String, Class<?>> entry : properties.entrySet()) {
  builder = builder.defineField(entry.getKey(), entry.getClass();
}
```

Note that the builder is immutable and you need to reassign it within the loop body.